# Proof of No Recursion implied by Axiom of Regularity

Tags: logic, set-theory

I was reading, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#2._Axiom_of_regularity_.28also_called_the_Axiom_of_foundation.29

And it claims the Axiom of regularity implies that no set can be a member of itself. I don't follow whats being conveyed here. Consider this example:

Let $L = \lbrace{1 , L} \rbrace$

or to do this in ZFC

Let $L = \lbrace  \lbrace  \emptyset \rbrace , L  \rbrace $

Then consider $L \cap \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace $

Obviously this is empty. So we meet the disjointedness condition, yet we can still have self membership. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Axiom of Regularity states that if $A$ is a non-empty set, then
there is $B\in A$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

In your example,
consider $A=\{L\}$. Is there $B\in A$ such that $A\cap B$ is empty.

Comment: I see. So by wrapping L into a set we can find a contradiction.